# post request in Axios with 400 or 401 - bearer token

Tags: json, reactjs, post, axios, bearer-token

I'm trying to post data using axios.

```
handleAddClickAxios = (token, title, text, category, creationDate) => {
  const api = "http://localhost:3000/tasks/";
  console.log("login clicked");
  let data = JSON.stringify({
    title: title,
    text: text,
    category: category,
    creationDate: creationDate,
    done: false
  });
  console.log(data);

  axios.post(api, data, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  });
};
```

Now I have 400 error, in some options I got Unauthorized error. I tried  many times, but i failed.

Console:

> Apptask -
>   eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZGNmZjFhMjQzZWUwNTJmNmNkMjAzYzgiLCJpYXQiOjE1NzQ1ODQzMDl9.P9cKtljoFXbCo6X540tQ27d_jeouOwwRJ6HKhpsy-PY
>   asdad
>
> App.js:100 login clicked
>
> App.js:108
>   {"title":"asdad","text":"aaaaaaaaaa","category":"","creationDate":"2019-10-0,
>   9:31","done":false} :3000/tasks/:1 POST http://localhost:3000/tasks/
>   400 (Bad Request)

Request details in devtools:

[image]

Comment: try sending data without JSON.stringify.

Comment: I tried, I got 400 Error too.

Comment: Also be sure you are sending valid creationDate, "2019-10-0, 9:31"  is not a valid date.

Comment: I changed creationDate to null, and i got 201 now :). So thanks for tip. In my Express route, i had type for CreationDate - Boolean....

Comment: Would you accept if I post an answer with these info?

Comment: No problem. I accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send data without JSON.stringify like this:

```
let data = {
  title,
  text,
  category,
  creationDate,
  done: false
};
```

Also your creationData is not valid, it must be in this format:

> "2019-11-24T09:06:29.271Z"